# populating multiple comboBoxes from elements in a string list

Tags: c#, .net, combobox

I have a list of input curve names in a text file called *inCurves.txt*. The .txt file reads:

```
18500*8500*Eval:c3*Eval:c2*Eval:c1*Final:DTS*Final:OBG*Final:PPG*
```

The first two numbers are bottom and top depth, while the remainder are curveSet names and curve names for every remaining comboBox (1 - 6)

I've written a script to populate comboBoxes from this .txt, but I receive an error when I try to convert `cmbBox` into `string`, and then into an integer.

> input string was not in a correct format)

```
private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string CurveNamesInText = "";
        char[] delimiter = { '*' };
        CurveNamesInText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Public\inCurves.txt");

        string[] crvIn = CurveNamesInText.Split(delimiter);

        string BottomDepth = crvIn[0];
        string TopDepth = crvIn[1];

        var combBoxes = this.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>().Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("comboBox"));

        foreach (var cmbBox in combBoxes)
        {
            string yes = Convert.ToString(cmbBox);
            string number = yes.Replace("comboBox","0");
            int i = Convert.ToInt16(number); //error here, comp doesn't like it
            MessageBox.Show("current number value \n" + number + "\n" + "current i value \n" + i);

            //cmbBox.Text = crvIn[6-i]; // this is what I'd like to do next
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error Loading Curve names \n" + ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

I would like to assign an element in crvIn list to each comboBox. Ideally, something like this:

```
cmbBox.Text = crvIn[i];
```

Can you help?

Comment: So use a break-point and check what the value `number` holds.

Comment: is it just one long text or are there multiple lines in that file? if so, you might wanna ReadAllLines and split them indivitually? Also what is the value of "number" when you try to parse it?

Comment: why do you convert and replace?=! what is the number good for?

Comment: There is only one line, and I split each element by the * delimiter to parse.

Comment: convert and replace? I guess the problem I'm running into is that I'm trying to run two loops at once: one "foreach" for every comboBox while the other (convert cmbBox to string, then to integer) on each element in my CrvIn list.

Comment: if you have only 1 line in the file, why do you need 6 comboboxes? don't you want to display just all values in one so that the user can choose between the options?=!

Comment: "I'm trying to run two loops at once". Now I get closer to understanding you. The second number is intended to work as a second indexer for the `crvIn` array ?=! Unfortunately this will not work, even if you would have gotten the name conversion correctly, because `Replace("comboBox","0");` will return always a `0` at each iteration so you would access always the same position in the array

Comment: each CurveSet:CurveName belongs in the text of a comboBox. For example, Eval:c3 belongs in ComboBox6. I saved the comboBox info into the .txt to be written as a single line with * as the delimiter.

Comment: Why do you want to use the `Text` property? What do you intend to do with the comboboxes afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to convert an entire object `ComboBox` into a string, which will result only in the full name of the class/type `ComboBox` plus the item count:

> "System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox Items.Count:0"

You can also see this in the Debugger.

> I would like to assign an element in crvIn list to each comboBox

I guess if you want to add each value to a different combobox you could use a for-loop and add the items. You need to add it to the items, if you want to make them selectable.

First you need to make a list from your query. Add `ToList()` at the end:

```
var combBoxes = this.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>()
                    .Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("comboBox")).ToList();

for (int i = 0; i < combBoxes.Count; i++)
{
    combBoxes[i].Text = crvIn[i + 2];
}
```

Comment: combBoxes.Count  does not seem to work, but this is the direction I'd like to take.

Comment: @endlessforms I oversaw that you are using an `IEnumerable`. I edited my post. You need to make a `List` by adding `ToList` at the end of your controls query to make it work

Comment: I changed Items.Add to  combBoxes[i].Text= crvIn[i] and this worked. Thank you!

Comment: @endlessforms ok I followed your change. Still don't really understand why you use the `Text` property. Is it only for display ?=!

Comment: Yes, only for display.

Comment: why don't you simply use a `TextBox` then, may be even read only?=!